# Error when trying to run a simple mojolicious program

Tags: perl, mojolicious

New to Mojolicious.  I have two files, test1.pl and test2.pm,  got error when trying to run it on my PC (Ubuntu 12.04).

```
$ morbo test1.pl 
Couldn't load application from file "test1.pl": Can't call method "render" on an undefined value at test2.pm line 11.
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Here are the two files

#########test1.pl

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
no warnings;
use test2;

get '/' => test2::sendMainPage;
```

#########test2.pm

```
package test2;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use URI::Escape;
use HTML::Entities;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;
use Exporter 'import';

sub sendMainPage {
    my $self  = shift;
    $self->render(text => q|<html><body>
<h1>Welcome to test demo page</h1>
</body></html>|);
}


1;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to pass a reference to your sub when setting up a route:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
no warnings;
use test2;

get '/' => \&test2::sendMainPage;
```

Otherwise, you're actually calling the sub with no parameters, and hence the error.

Also, don't do this `no warnings;`.  Include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) at the top of each and every script script you make.  There are many reasons why [`Mojolicious::Lite`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite) turns on those pragmas by default.

If you had done that, you would've gotten this warning which would've alerted you to the problem:

```
Bareword "test2::sendMainPage" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at test1.pl line 5.
```

And finally, always capitalize your package names.  `Test2` instead of '`test2`.  From [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html)

> Perl informally reserves lowercase module names for "pragma" modules like integer and strict . Other modules should begin with a capital letter and use mixed case, but probably without underscores due to limitations in primitive file systems' representations of module names as files that must fit into a few sparse bytes.

Final working code:

test1.pl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojolicious::Lite;

use Test2;

get '/' => \&Test2::sendMainPage;

app->start;

__DATA__
```

Test2.pm

```
package Test2;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub sendMainPage {
    my $self  = shift;
    $self->render(text => q|<html><body>
<h1>Welcome to test demo page</h1>
</body></html>|);
}

1;

__DATA__
```